Why is Wigner-Seitz cell considered primitive?
During the lecture I listened, as well as in the internet, in Wikipedia for example, unit cell was defined as the parallelepiped spanned by the translation vectors. Primitive cell was defined as the smallest unit cell containing only 1 lattice point. We were also given an algorithm for constructing the WS cell in 2D. We were also told that it is a primitive cell.
The thing that confuses me is the fact that the WS cell in most cases ends up being not a parallelogram, while unit cell and primitive cell must be parallelograms (parallelepipeds) by definition. Could anyone help me resolve this issue with terms and definitions?

The Wigner-Switzerland cell most definitely is a primitive unit cell, by construction. Any ‘definition’ that does not permit WS to be a primitive cell is incorrect.

@JonCuster thank you for your response! Could you then please share a source that would provide a clear definition of these terms and clearly explain how they differ?

The definition and construction of the Wigner-Seitz cell is covered in any solid state physics textbook. I think the stumbling block is the 'parallelepiped' bit - that is more restrictive than polyhedral. In particular, parallel faces will occur for directions of inversion symmetry. But not all crystals have inversion symmetry.
